# Too many constants, the constant pool for Main would exceed 65536 entries in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I am working on a project where I need to design a 5 storied building. But during running the model, I have getting the following error

Too many constants, the constant pool for Main would exceed 65536 entries

Is there a way to solve this on Anylogic?

Comment: here
https://noorjax.com/2018/10/17/your-agent-is-too-big-memory-problem/